# VBA to fill cells with vlookup, copy and paste into other cells. I have a Macro that works fine except when

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have this Macro I wrote to filter and sort the sheet and then add in the vlookup formula next to any cell that says "short paid".  My code works fine if there's more than one row that has the "short paid" in column G.

When it's just one row that has the "short paid" in column G the Macro starts using the header, copying and pasting what's in the header (row 1) into row2.  I just find it strange that if there's more than one row with "short paid" the macro doesn't touch the header at all.  here's the code:

```
Sub Prox2()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim xRow As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRows As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
    "Short Paid"

LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("H2") = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)": Range("H2:H" & 
LastRow).FillDown

Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=True, Transpose:=False

Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Range("H2") = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:P,16,FALSE)": Range("H2:H" & 
LastRow).FillDown

Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Range("C2") = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:F,6,FALSE)": Range("C2:C" & 
LastRow).FillDown

Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Range("F2") = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:J,10,FALSE)": Range("F2:F" & 
LastRow).FillDown

Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Range("E2") = "=F2-30": Range("E2:E" & LastRow).FillDown

ActiveSheet.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=7

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest avoid using `.Select` copy/paste method as it's quite slow... I'd suggest just using the `Worksheet.Range([RANGE]).Formula = [FORMULA]` as it is much faster

Comment: @Maldred so would that solve the macro from using the header where there's only one row that needs a vlookup?

Comment: It'd be much easier to `Debug`, I can't say for certain that it'll fix your issue, but your code could definitely use a rework

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you try to find LastRow (LastRow = ...) you are not checking for the possibility that there may by no rows. You should add:

```
If LastRow = 1 Then
    'This means no rows found. Exit or do something else.
```

Edit:

Try this approach:

```
Range("H2:H" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1, Sheet2!C1:C2, 2, FALSE)"
```

Comment: the thing is there IS a row.  Just one row and the header thats when the macros doesn't work.  If its 2 rows or more with the words "short paid" in the cell, the macros works.  But if its just one row with the words "short paid" in the cell, the macros starts using the header row to insert data into row 2.  I only call this macro if i do see a row with "short paid" So i don't need to use an If statement to exit out since i wouldn't use it in the first place if i didn't see "short paid"

Comment: Yes, well when there is one row the FillDown method will copy from the row above, which is the header row. So when there is only one row you should only populate the formula in that one row, and not use the FillDown method.

Comment: So is there a way to implement a code that if there is only one row with data (header row on top of course) to not use the filldown method?  Like what you wrote, something like If LastRow = 2 then (saying 2 because there would be 2 rows, header row, and one row of data needing the vlookup formula) ?

Comment: I wouldn't use Filldown at all. I suspect it would populate the formula into the filtered rows as well as the unfiltered rows. I'll add a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: So if i didn't use .filldown what would my code suppose to look like? thanks in advance